# not found css file in cakephp without rewrite module

Tags: php, css, cakephp, file-not-found

I'm having a problem with CakePHP, the CSS is not found. When I view the source code in my browser I can see the cake generic CSS link in the head section. But when I click on it to see the actual source code, I get a 404 not found error.
i follow this actions:

1. uncommented

   ```
   Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));
   ```

   in app/config/core.php , because rewrite module is disable.
2. delete `.htaccess` file from `/` and `/app` and `/app/webroot`.
3. run project.

php code in default is :

> app/View/Layouts/default.ctp

```
echo $this->Html->css('cake.generic');
```

and its html code is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/app/webroot/css/cake.generic.css" />
```

this file exist really, but when i click to `/app/webroot/css/cake.generic.css` in source of browser code i face

> 404 Not Found

Is way?

Comment: Where is your virtual host document root pointing to? `app/webroot`?

Comment: my project in doorway folder and path is: `/home2/persianv/public_html/doorway/app/webroot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your virtual hosts document root points to `app/webroot` so your links to the css files need to point to `/css/file.css`. The way you have it now it's actually looking for `app/webroot/app/webroot/css` and that's why you get a 404.

Either that or your .htaccess is wrong or you stylesheet doesn't actually exist. Let me know if this helps and i can update my answer if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Already,i face this problem. i change permission for app and webroot and css folders. i offer this for you too.

Comment: where is the solution ?